# How to properly split streaming text into paragraphs?

Tags: java, string, nlp, text-processing

I am using okhttp subscribing to a `SSE`( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) stream, the `onEvent` callback is use to receive new data from upstream and passed by `data` param as `String`

It takes too long to wait for all data to arrive and is too frequent to send on every single char arriving, and I need to send proper data segment intermitently.

```
// initiate an SSE request and receive new data by `onEvent`
eventSourceFactory.newEventSource(request, new EventSourceListener() {
    // onEvent called every time remote send new data, `data` is new data
    public void onEvent(EventSource eventSource, String id, String type, String data) {
        // pseudo code below
        String stringToSend = process(data, minSplitLength);
        if (!stringToSend.isEmpty()) {
            send(stringToSend);
        }
    }
})
```

**So I want to impl `process(String data, int minSplitLength);` method**

**It should properly store stream data and emits string `stringToSend`  with length larger than `minSplitLength` e.g. when a paragraph or a sentence is constructed from `data`s with length >= `minSplitLength` or empty string**

The `data` param can contain any mainstream natural language, e.g. **en-US**, **zh-CN**, **Russian**, **Arabic**, **ja-JP** , etc

I can accept occasionally non-perfect splitting.

Any other ideas, for example split base both on text content and time is also welcome.

I want to impl this in Java.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? You describe a whole problem. What have you tried? Are you looking for an algorithm? What are the data types? Since you mention languages: what sentence/paragraph ending indicators do you need to/want to accept? Just `.` or also the Japanes `。` and Arabic `۔`?

Comment: You need proper rules to define a "paragraph", because even if you just worked with English, you could get some `.` that doesn't mark a paragraph, like in `1.` numbered list items or abbreviations like `etc.`.

Comment: thanks, I was expecting some NLP magic automatically determine whether one position in string is the end of a paragraph or the end of a sentence.

Comment: [`BreakIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/BreakIterator.html)…